# Extjs: get access to components while the parent panel container "display:none"

Tags: extjs, accessibility

if the parent panel is set as "display:none", how could Extjs code get access to the components in this panel?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any JavaScript application has access to any component or element in a web page, whether or not it is visible.  If you have a reference to a node, you can always read it or change it.  If that doesn't answer your question, please provide more information.

Comment: i think it's my mistake. there's something wrong in somewhere else, not relevant to this issue. thanks for your answer!

Comment: In that case, it must be that the implementation of the collapsible panel you're using removes the elements from the DOM after hiding, or that the `find()` method automatically skips elements that aren't visible.  Try assigning an `id` attribute to one of your checkboxes and use `document.getElementById(id)` directly to see if it still exists.